# should not click on the previously form [C#]

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

In my form i have button to show other form.

But i want the previously form cannot be clicked before the new form is closed , How to create that ?

Because if the previously form is clicked, and i click the button again, the form is show multiple.
this my code in button click :

```
MDACS_AOP_CFSTL_InputActivity addProblem = new MDACS_AOP_CFSTL_InputActivity(ParameterSesi, ParameterNamaKaryawan, ParameterTanggal);
                    //addProblem.Close();
                    addProblem.Show();
```

Comment: Try if MDACS_AOP_CFSTL_InputActivity provides a ShowDialog() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
addProblem.ShowDialog();
```

instead of

```
addProblem.Show();
```

so that it will open a modal dialog.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
addProblem.ShowDialog(this);
```

This will open the dialog as child of the parent (this) dialog. You cant click the parent dialog but you can still see it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
 MDACS_AOP_CFSTL_InputActivity addProblem = new MDACS_AOP_CFSTL_InputActivity(ParameterSesi, ParameterNamaKaryawan, ParameterTanggal);
 this.Hide;
 addProblem.ShowDialog();
 this.Show();
```

The show(); command will not be executed until the dialog is close. So it will stay hidden

Comment: Thanks the code works, but i dont need hide the form, i just use the ShowDialog() and thats work thank you.

Comment: Just want to add for information that if you use "this" the scope will be changed when new pop up shown. either you can use the form name directly. :D